# Create table from Json response using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am trying to create a table using Json response and Knockout.js

In Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
       url : "devTestServlet",
       success : function(data) {

           ko.applyBindings({ 
               rows : data
               });
       }
       });
});
```

In HTML first of all I imported scripts in header:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"></link>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then in body I did following:

```
<table >
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Finish Date</th>
<th>Position</th>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
<tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Start_Date"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Finish_Date"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Position"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Format of the data looks like following:

```
[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Mike",
            "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Position": "Trainee"

        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Jhon",
            "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Position": "Trainee"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Jhon",
            "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
            "Position": "Trainee"
        }
]
```

This is my first program with Knockout.js so may be I am missing something. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: Code is written following instruction from this link: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.ajax` returns the response as a string by default, knockout needs a JavaScript object. So you either have to specify `dataType` as `JSON`

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "devTestServlet",
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function(data) {
       ko.applyBindings({ 
           rows : data
       });
   }
});
```

or do the conversion yourself

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "devTestServlet",
   success: function(data) {
       ko.applyBindings({ 
           rows : JSON.parse(data)
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. specially to Malvin! Your advice worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put jQuery before Knockout JS in your libraries.
2. Make sure `rows` is a `ko.observableArray()`;
3. Change: `ko.applyBindings({ rows : data });` to: `rows(data);`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

You should add the bindings and update them.
It should look a little something like this:

```
var HomeModel = function() {
    this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var model = new HomeModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
       url : "devTestServlet",
       success : function(data) {
           for (var x in data) {
               model.rows.push(data[x]);
           }
       }
       });
});
```

Since 'rows' is now an 'observableArray' it will update your HTML agains changes.
Goodluck!

Comment: @ChrisDixon You're right but I use it that way because in this scenario I would also create a RowModel and use model.rows.push(new RowModel(data[x]) in stead of plain JSON.

Answer (score 0):

1. jQuery reference should be before the knockout.js
2. other than that your code is fine and works  for me personally: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/eybZ6/

I'd recommend placing a stylesheet refernce in the  and the script refs somewhere at the bottom of the page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <content />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Do you thing I should do anything with received data on success. Like parsing or anything.   success : function(data) {
        //var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        var result = data;
        console.log(result);
        ko.applyBindings({
             rows: data
         });
   
       }